# Controlar SWF Principal através de um SWF externo

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

No `actionscript2` era possível, mais no `actionscript3` não estou conseguindo fazer.
É o seguinte, eu tenho um arquivo SWF principal que contem alguns movieClips. O meu arquivo principal carrega um outro SWF externo que contem uma animação.

Minha animação contem alguns momentos que eu gostaria de acionar as mascaras (MC) no meu arquivo principal para gerar uns efeitos visuais, só que eu não consigo disparar meus movieClips através do arquivo externo.

Já tentei usar `parent.parent` entre outros sem sucesso e a animação é muito grande para carregar antes de exibir o arquivo principal, se não eu jogava tudo dentro do principal e funcionaria.

Comment: você está adicionando o swf externo no `stage` ou dentro de um outro movieClip? Está usando packages para organizar o projeto, ou está escrevendo tudo dentro da "animação"? A mascara você conseguiu aplicar? O que seria disparar, seria o `play`? Você quer dar `stop` e `play` na animação externa ou elas simplesmente deveriam rodar automaticamente, mas não carregam?

Comment: O SWF externo esta sendo carregado dentro de um movie clip.

Comment: O arquivo externo estou colocando as acoes na timeline da animacao

Comment: Eu gostaria que o arquivo externo desse um gotoAndStop() em uma mascara que esta no SWF principal que esta diretamente sobre o palco do arquivo Principal.

Comment: Eu gostaria de dar Stop e Play nos MC´s do arquivo pricipal, atravez do arquivo Externo, ou seja, conforme a timeline do arquivo Externo, vai avançando, ela vai disparando as mascaras do  do arquivo Principal(main). Estou fazendo algo similar a isso http://www.takethislollipop.com/ . Já carrego todas as informacoes e fotos dos usuarios dentro dos MovieClilps, e sobre eles tem uma mascara, que conforme a TimeLine do arquivo com o clip (arquvo externo) vai rodando vai mostrando as imagens nos momentos corretos.

Comment: Sua resposta: *O SWF externo esta sendo carregado dentro de um movie clip.* Isto deve ser o problema, o movieClip deve ter um name, este name deve ser apontado, não? Ou você quer que o movieClip externo controle o movieClip que carregou ele?

Comment: isso mesmo eu gostaria que o SWF externo controle o movieClip